# Enabling variants in Bison

Tags: bison, variant

I have trouble making variants work in bison. I put in

```
%{
  ... 
%}

%define api.value.type variant
...
%%
...
```

But I get

```
bison -d -t -o parser.cpp parser.ypp
parser.ypp:16.9-22: error: '"yacc.c"' does not support '%define api.value.type variant'
%define api.value.type variant
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

My version is supposed to support variants.

```
bison --version
bison (GNU Bison) 3.0.2
Written by Robert Corbett and Richard Stallman.

Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO 
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the error message talks about "yacc.c", it's referring to the "yacc" skeleton for the C language. Variants are a C++ feature. Use `%language "c++"` to set the language to C++ and it will work.